# ggplot2: minor breaks in scale_x_datetime

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
.months <- 3
.minor.intervals <- 4
.minor.intervals.num <- .months * .minor.intervals
sdate <- as.POSIXct("2015-01-01")
edate <- sdate + months(.months)
df <- data.frame(x = seq(from = sdate, to = edate,
                         length.out = .minor.intervals.num * 2),
                 y = 1:(.minor.intervals.num * 2))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y))
xbm <- seq(from = sdate, to = edate, length.out = .minor.intervals.num)
p <- p + scale_x_datetime(limits = c(sdate, edate),
                          breaks = date_breaks("month"),
                          minor_breaks = xbm)
p <- p + geom_line() + geom_point()
plot(p)
```

gives me error: `Error in Ops.POSIXt((x - from[1]), diff(from)) :  '/' not defined for "POSIXt" objects`

If I comment `minor_breaks` part — everything works.

If I change `minor_breaks` part to `minor_breaks = date_breaks("week")` — everything works too.

But I want to split month exactly for 4 parts...

How to fix it?

Comment: Your solution would, even if it worked, not lead to the months being split into exactly four parts. The reason is that months are not equidistant. If you look at `xbm`, you'll notice that the only major breaks appearing in there are the first and the last.

Comment: @Stibu, yeah, sorry, in real code minor_breaks calculates fine, I just oversimplified code :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to solve the problem, but I must admit that I am not sure why it has to be done this way. It seems that `minor_breaks` expects numeric values and not dates as input.

I created the breaks with the following code:

```
maj.breaks <- sdate + months(0:.months)
min.breaks <- do.call(c,
   lapply(1:.months,function(m) {
         seq(maj.breaks[m],maj.breaks[m+1],length.out = .minor.intervals+1)
   })
)
```

which relies on the variables as defined in your example. Note the difference to your way of defining the minor breaks: since each month has different length, it is not enough to simply split the range between the start and end dates into the appropriate number of segments. You have to split each month by itself.

As mentioned above, you then have to convert `min.breaks` to numeric before you pass it to `minor_breaks`. I produce the plot as follows:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
      scale_x_datetime(limits = c(sdate, edate),
                       breaks = maj.breaks,
                       minor_breaks = as.numeric(min.breaks)) +
      geom_line() + geom_point()
plot(p)
```

This is identical to your code up to the inputs for `breaks` and `minor_breaks`. There is no need to use the vector `maj.breaks` since your version works just as well. But I think it is interesting to note that `breaks` works with input of class `POSIXct`, while `minor_breaks` expects numeric values. Unfortunately, I don't know the reason for this.

[image]

Comment: as.numeric(min.breaks) works for me, thanks. Still wondering why POSIXt don't work with scale_x_datetime.